# What is the size of screen shots for play store and app sote

Tags: mobile

Anyone tell me what should be the size of screen shots for play store and android.

thanks

Comment: Can't you find an existing screenshot on one of these sites, and download it? Then you could check the size in almost any image editor or image viewer.

Answer (score 0):

[From Google help docs - Graphic assets, screenshots, & video](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en)

> **Requirements** To publish your Store Listing, you must provide a minimum of 2 screenshots.
>
> - JPEG or 24-bit PNG (no alpha)
> - Minimum dimension: 320px
> - Maximum dimension: 3840px
> - The maximum dimension of your screenshot can't be more than twice as long as the minimum dimension.